# In the "Songs" package, how do I customize the song number?

Tags: songs

I'm using the `Songs` package and would like to have rounded corners for the song number and center the song number inside the rounded square. I already changed the grey color to orange.

1. How to customize with rounded corners?
2. How to vertically and horizontally center the number?

See below my MWE and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{g_songnumbercolor}{RGB}{255, 142, 39}
\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{g_songnumbercolor}
\renewcommand{\printsongnum}[1]{\color{white}\bfseries\Huge#1}
\noversenumbers
\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Some song title}[sr={in D}, by={Some other info}]
\beginverse
\[D]Some lyrics
Again \[A]some other lyrics
\endverse
\endsong
\beginsong{Some song title 2}[sr={in F}, by={Some other info}]
\beginverse
\[F]Some lyrics
Again \[A]some other lyrics
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of my MWE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt, based on a little booklet I recently did:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}

\definecolor{g_songnumbercolor}{RGB}{255, 142, 39}

\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{white}

\newcommand*\squared[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, fill=g_songnumbercolor,draw,line width=1.5pt,inner sep=3pt] (char) {#1};}}

\renewcommand{\printsongnum}[1]{\sffamily\color{white}\bfseries\Huge\squared{#1}}

\noversenumbers
\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Some song title}[sr={in D}, by={Some other info}]
\beginverse
\[D]Some lyrics
Again \[A]some other lyrics
\endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Some song title 2}[sr={in F}, by={Some other info}]
\beginverse
\[F]Some lyrics
Again \[A]some other lyrics
\endverse
\endsong

\end{songs}
\end{document}
```

It uses Ti*k*Z.

**ETA**: I have changed the code to produce a rounded rectangle instead of a circle, as requested by OP.

[image]

Comment: Great already ! Initially, I would like a rounded rectangle and saw it's possible in Tikz documentation (shape=rounded rectangle). I've tried to update your code but with no success.. I've put the same comment in previous solution because i'ts like you have a different approch with using Tkiz. thank !

Comment: @podosta: That what you are looking for? I have switched from circles to rounded rectangles.

Comment: defenitivly ! Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

By default this is a simple box, but you can redefine it to use tikz and then use all the tikz options:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[chorded]{songs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{g_songnumbercolor}{RGB}{255, 142, 39}
\renewcommand{\snumbgcolor}{g_songnumbercolor}
\renewcommand{\printsongnum}[1]{\color{white}\bfseries\Huge#1}
\noversenumbers
\setlength{\sbarheight}{0pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\SB@colorbox[2]{\tikz{\node[left color=red,right color=g_songnumbercolor,circle]{#2};}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{songs}{}
\beginsong{Some song title}[sr={in D}, by={Some other info}]
\beginverse
\[D]Some lyrics
Again \[A]some other lyrics
\endverse
\endsong
\beginsong{Some song title 2}[sr={in F}, by={Some other info}]
\beginverse
\[F]Some lyrics
Again \[A]some other lyrics
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great already ! Initially, I would like a rounded rectangle and saw it's possible in Tikz documentation (shape=rounded rectangle). I've tried to update your code but with no success.. Also, I would like to center the number inside, any idea ?